# How to make a .json axios readable in django-rest?

Tags: json, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to fetch a JSON from API on axios vue.

How this link `/api/v1/rainfall/?format=json` to `rainfall.json` link on django-rest?

@views.py

```
class RainfallView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RainfallSerializer
    queryset = Rainfall.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = RainfallSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

@axios on vue.

```
async created(){
        const {data} = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/rainfall/?format=json');
```

but it returns a blank response. how to have an output to my graph? Thanks

Comment: post the url.py where `?format=json` query params processed

Comment: so check n network tab of devtools for what actual response you are getting. it should clarify where the problem is i.e in rest-framework or vue

Comment: Hello this is the urls.py `path('v1/rainfall/', RainfallView.as_view()),` should I edit it as .json to make it .json format? or it will automatically do it if certain settings are set?

Comment: should not need `?format=json`; what about  network tab of devtools? what data you are getting ?

Comment: I get nothing, it's blank.

Comment: does `Rainfall` has any matching entry available ?

Comment: btw what is `rainfall.json` ?

Comment: Yes, rainfall have entry available.

it has: entities on model, will make a graph. 
- level
- amount
- timestamp

Comment: well, I am not seeing any problem here; try debugging in following way: 1. print(serializer.data) before `return Response(...` what is output ?. 2. `return Response({ 'test': 'String'})` what is input in chrome devtools ?

Comment: I found out what the problem is, after observing console. I found out that CORS restricting access. haha sorry. but Thanks for answering my post. :)